# Azure Service Bus to Azure DB - Two way message writing

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azureservicebus

Do Azure support posting data from Azure Service Bus to Azure DB?

I want to use this as a work around as I am not able to connect to Azure Service Bus because of AMPQ protocol.

On the other hand connecting to Azure DB is easy for the platform I am using.

Answer (score 2):

First: You don't need to connect to the Service Bus with AMQP protocol. Service Bus support REST. It is the EventHub that supports the AMQP protocol.

How do you get a Service Bus message into a Azure SQL Database
This can be done in several ways. You can have a WebJob or a Worker Role that listen to the queue. You can also create a App Service Logic App that reads from the queue and saves the data into the database.

/dag

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can only add on-premise (locally running) data gateway for connecting a Service Bus Queue to SQL Server DB even your services run on the cloud.